# Proving a group is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group with the property that in every subset of 4 distinct elements, there exists at least a pair of commuting elements.
Show that G is Abelian.

- I have thought so far that if G isn't abelian then if x,y dont commute and given subset of index 3 then the subset $\{x,y,xy\} \implies xy = yx$. Can I find something similar for the 4-element case?

Comment: $xy = yx \iff x(yx) = (yx)x \iff x(xy)=(xy)x\iff (yx)y=y(yx)\iff (xy)y = y(xy)$. $xy=yx\implies xyyx=yxxy$ and $xyyx=yxxy\implies...$ hmm, you may be right.  I was assuming nick's calculations were good.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The theorem is incorrect. The quaternion group $Q_8$ is a counterexample, where $Q_8 = \{1, i, j, k, -1, -i, -j, -k\}$.

In this group, every element commutes with its negative. Also, $1$ and $-1$ commute with eveything. By the pidgeonhole principle, every 4-element subset of $Q_8$ either contains $1$, $-1$, or both an element and its negative. Hence, there is a commuting pair in every 4-element subset of $Q_8$.

But $Q_8$ is non-abelian, since $ij \ne ji$.

Thanks to @DanielFisher for his help.